# How to open a template as modal (detail user data) in user_list page (Django 1.11)

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a user list page which works fine, and a user detail page which works fine too that I call from urls.py in seperate window. I want to open user detail in user list page in a modal window.

**user_list.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}

    <tr userid="{{user.id}}" class="edit_user">
      <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{user.username }}</td>
      <td>
        <form class="right user_delete" method="POST" userid="{{user.id}}"
          action="{% url 'user_delete' user.id%}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" value="DELETE">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit_user" href="{% url 'user_details' user.id %}" target="#edit_user"> UPDATE </a></td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    <tr>
      <td>No Projects.</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerformmodal"> New user </button>
```

**user_detail.html**

```
<h1>User Details</h1>
<p>{{ user_details.username }}</p>
<p>{{ user_details.first_name }}</p>
```

**views.py**

```
def user_details(request, userid):
    user = User.objects.get(id=userid)
    template = loader.get_template('vts/user_detail.html')
    context = {
        'user_details': user,
    }
    return HttpResponse (template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: Use bootstrap for your templates to look pleasing. Check this link for implementing modal https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: i used bootstrap modal but i could not load data in it.

Answer (score 0):

The button `data-target` here,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerformmodal"> New user </button>
```

looks for `#registerformmodal` which is neither associated with `<form>` nor `<div>`

You can add the id to your form as this

```
<form id="#registerformmodal" class="right user_delete" method="POST" userid="{{user.id}}">
...
</form>
```